# Gradescope is showing my code is incorrect , question and code is below

Tags: c++

Write a program that inputs four numbers separated by spaces.  The program should count how many odd and even numbers there are. The program should then output one of three possibilities depending on how many even and odd numbers are entered:

more evens
more odds
same number of evens and odds

For example, an execution could look like this:

Please enter 4 positive integers, separated by a space: 2 3 5 7
more odds

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, num4;
    cout << "Plese enter 4 positive integers, seperated by space:" << endl;
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4;
    if ((num1 % 2 == 0) && (num2 % 2 == 0) && (num3 % 2 == 0) && (num4 % 2 == 0)) {
        cout << "more evens" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 != 0) && (num2 % 2 == 0) && (num3 % 2 == 0) && (num4 % 2 == 0)) {
        cout << "more evens" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 == 0) && (num2 % 2 != 0) && (num3 % 2 == 0) && (num4 % 2 == 0)) {
        cout << "more evens" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 == 0) && (num2 % 2 == 0) && (num3 % 2 != 0) && (num4 % 2 == 0)) {
        cout << "more evens" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 == 0) && (num2 % 2 == 0) && (num3 % 2 == 0) && (num4 % 2 != 0)) {
        cout << "more evens" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 != 0) && (num2 % 2 != 0) && (num3 % 2 == 0) && (num4 % 2 == 0)) {
        cout << "same number of odds and evens" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 != 0) && (num2 % 2 == 0) && (num3 % 2 != 0) && (num4 % 2 == 0)) {
        cout << "same number of odds and evens" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 != 0) && (num2 % 2 == 0) && (num3 % 2 == 0) && (num4 % 2 != 0)) {
        cout << "same number of odds and evens" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 == 0) && (num2 % 2 != 0) && (num3 % 2 != 0) && (num4 % 2 == 0)) {
        cout << "same number of odds and evens" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 == 0) && (num2 % 2 == 0) && (num3 % 2 != 0) && (num4 % 2 != 0)) {
        cout << "same number of odds and evens" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 != 0) && (num2 % 2 != 0) && (num3 % 2 != 0) && (num4 % 2 == 0)) {
        cout << "more odds" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 != 0) && (num2 % 2 != 0) && (num3 % 2 == 0) && (num4 % 2 != 0)) {
        cout << "more odds" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 != 0) && (num2 % 2 == 0) && (num3 % 2 != 0) && (num4 % 2 != 0)) {
        cout << "more odds" << endl;
    }
    else if ((num1 % 2 == 0) && (num2 % 2 != 0) && (num3 % 2 != 0) && (num4 % 2 != 0)) {
        cout << "more odds" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "more odds" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If nothing else, this program prints `same number of odds and evens` where the problem statement requires `same number of evens and odds`

Comment: There are 16 possibilities, but the program only has 15 print statements.

Comment: Test with `2 3 4 5`

Comment: Do you not feel that you have written too much code for such a small task. You could just record the count of odd numbers in c1 and count of even numbers in c2 and then just compare c1 and c2.

Comment: The shown approach is fundamentally wrong. The correct solution will be capable of making the same calculation for a billion numbers, and not just four, simply by changing one line in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your program.  Simple programs have fewer issues.

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, num4;
    cout << "Plese enter 4 positive integers, seperated by space:" << endl;
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4;
    int evens = 0;
    int odds = 0;
    if ((num1 % 2) == 0) ++evens; else ++odds;
    if ((num2 % 2) == 0) ++evens; else ++odds;
    if ((num3 % 2) == 0) ++evens; else ++odds;
    if ((num4 % 2) == 0) ++evens; else ++odds;
    if (evens > odds)
    {
        cout << "more evens\n";
    }
    if (odds > evens) cout << "more odds\n";
    if (odds == evens) cout << "same quantity evens and odds\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The above program counts the quantity of evens and the quantity of odds, then analyzes and prints the appropriate statement.